# Form sends blank/null serialized data

Tags: php, ajax, forms, sqlite, serialization

I've got an HTML form that uses jQuery serialize method and ajax to post results using PHP into a sqlite database. I've set the jQuery to run every minute to act as an autosave feature so users can return later to finish what they started. Because of the autosave, I can't force all inputs be required.

It works 99% of the time. However, in a few cases, the application sometimes posts blank data to the database even though there is data in the input fields. I've checked to make sure all the HTML input fields have **name** attributes. Any ideas why it works most of the time but in a few random cases, it doesn't?

I wish I had more to report why it doesn't work all the time. I haven't been able to replicate the bug myself, I'm just going on reports of users. But I know the form is posting blanks into the database because when I go into the database, it says " " instead of "*null*". So I know the database is receiving something, but it isn't receiving the data the user typed.

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" id="evaluationForm">
  <!-- this input is disabled since this user can't edit it -->
  <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['FirstName']);?>" disabled >
  <label for="WorkHabitsCommentsSuper">Comments </label><br>
  <textarea name="WorkHabitsCommentsSuper" placeholder="Comments are optional">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['WorkHabitsCommentsSuper']);?>
  </textarea>
  <label for="GoalsSuper">More Comments</label>
  <textarea name="GoalsSuper" required>
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['GoalsSuper']);?>
  </textarea>
  <!-- and a whole bunch more fields but you get the idea -->
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function saveEval() {
var datastring = $("form").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "autosave-s.php",
    data: datastring,
    success: function(text) {
        if (text == "success") {
            alert('It saved. Hooray!');
        } else {
            alert('Oh no. Something went wrong.');
        }
    }
});
}
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval("saveEval()", 60000)
}
```

PHP

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:evals.sqlite');
$sql = "UPDATE table SET
                WorkHabitsCommentsSuper = :WorkHabitsCommentsSuper,
                GoalsSuper = :GoalsSuper";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(
    ':WorkHabitsCommentsSuper' => $_POST['WorkHabitsCommentsSuper'],
    ':GoalsSuper' => $_POST['GoalsSuper']
));
echo "success";
```

Comment: How do you know there is input data in the fields? There's nothing stopping the user from deleting the input.

Comment: You are right @Barmar - I don't know if there is input data in the fields. It is an internal application and I'm only going off reports from employees who use the application. But I've seen users print a PDF of what they entered only to go back later and have all the data disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!in_array("",$_POST)){
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:evals.sqlite');
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET
    WorkHabitsCommentsSuper = :WorkHabitsCommentsSuper,
    GoalsSuper = :GoalsSuper";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
    ':WorkHabitsCommentsSuper' => $_POST['WorkHabitsCommentsSuper'],
    ':GoalsSuper' => $_POST['GoalsSuper']
    ));
    echo "success";
}else{
   echo "Empty";
}
```

This will check if the posting data is not empty if empty any of the field it will not update and will send 'Empty' response so alert on empty data posting.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @smehsoud. I thought about doing something like this, but then it would break the auto save feature. I was trying to create an application that would auto save every minute (similar to how Google Docs and other apps automatically save) and that requires that the data save to the database even if there are blank or empty fields. But maybe I can check if **all** fields are empty and alert the user otherwise. I'll try that out.